# VM does not have Sleep settings

Tags: virtual-machine, sleep, hyper-v, hibernate, power-management

I have Windows 10 Professional and Hyper-V. In one of the VMs, running Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation, the Sleep setting in the Power Options is as follows:

[image]

It does not have `Sleep after` and `Hibernate after` that are in the same Power Options found on my host computer (see below). **How do I control when the VM goes to sleep or shut off?**

[image]

I don't know whether it is related, but the VM now shuts itself down after some time. I don't know what type of shut down, ie Sleep or Hibernate or Power off, it is.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done in CMD, run CMD as admin and run the following command:

> powercfg /Change "settingvalue" 0

bellow you will have the settingsvalues for the different settings. The 0 at the end indicates how many minutes before it will be triggered, 0 means never.

For hibernate this command will be used:

> ```
> powercfg /Change hibernate-timeout-ac 0
>
> or 
>
> powercfg /Change hibernate-timeout-dc 0
> ```

```
/Change settingvalue    
/x setting value
            Modify one of the following settings in the current power scheme:
               monitor-timeout-ac minutes
               monitor-timeout-dc minutes
               disk-timeout-ac minutes
               disk-timeout-dc minutes
               standby-timeout-ac minutes
               standby-timeout-dc minutes
               hibernate-timeout-ac minutes
               hibernate-timeout-dc minutes
            Setting any value to 0 will set the timeout=Never
            AC settings are used when the system is on AC power. DC settings on battery power.
```

for more docs on powercfg [look here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options)